# Can Sri Krishna be called 'a person'?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

In Gita, Sri Krishna says:

> 4.6 Though **I am birthless, undecaying by nature**, and the Lord of beings, (still) by subjugating My Prakriti, I take birth by means of My own Maya.
>
> 4.9 He who thus knows truly **the divine birth and actions of Mine** does not get birth after casting off the body. He attains Me, O Arjuna.
>
> 7.24 **The unintelligent, unaware of My supreme state which is immutable and unsurpassable, think of Me as the unmanifest that has become manifest.**

We have also to remember that

> 2.28 O descendant of Bharata, all beings remain unmanifest in the beginning;; they become manifest in the middle. After death they certainly become unmanifest. What lamentation can there be with regard to them?

So Sri Krishna makes it clear that He is different from 'Unmanisfest' becoming 'Manifest' as are ALL the persons.

Given the above, does any of our scriptures allow to brand Sri Krishna as a 'Person' ('Vyakti') with 'Personality'?

**The meanings of the word 'Person' according to the the Oxford Dictionary are :**

> 1A human being regarded as an individual.
>
> •‘the porter was the last person to see her prior to her disappearance’
>   ‘she is a person of astonishing energy’
>   More example sentencesSynonyms
>   1.1 (in legal or formal contexts) an unspecified individual.
>   ‘each of the persons using unlawful violence is guilty of riot’
>   ‘the entrance fee is £2.00 per person’
>   More example sentences
>   1.2with modifier An individual characterized by a preference or liking for a specified thing.
>   ‘she's not a cat person’
>   More example sentencesSynonyms
>   1.3 A character in a play or story.
>   ‘his previous roles in the person of a fallible cop’
>   Synonyms
>   1.4 An individual's body.
>   ¤‘I would have publicity photographs on my person at all times’
>   More example sentencesSynonyms
>
> 2Grammar 
>   《A category used in the classification of pronouns, possessive determiners, and verb forms, according to whether they indicate the speaker (first person), the addressee (second person), or a third party (third person).
>
> 《Example sentences
>   《3Christian Theology 
>   《Each of the three modes of being of God, namely the Father, the Son, or the Holy Ghost, who together constitute the Trinity.

The Christan Theology meaning of course in not applicable in this case.

Are there any Non ISKCON translations which translate Krishna as "person"?

Comment: How would you define a person? Any conscious entity is qualified to be a person?

Comment: @Lazy Lubber person and vyakti both have dictionary meanings

Comment: The meaning I saw is - a man or a woman or a human being. Obviously, with this meaning, Krishna is not a person.

Comment: Please define what you mean by person, vyakti according to dictionary in your question

Comment: Yes, mostly Iskcon people say he is a person. But obviously they cant mean to say he is human. So what do they mean by the word person? May be only they can clarify.

Comment: Better you add since there may be multiple meanings and we can know what you really meant when you asked the question

Comment: @LazyLubber He is transcendental whose body is not of any matter, but of suddha sattva...and sat, cid and ananda form. But he has a body, he is not formless. he having a body is not the same as we having a body where soul and body are different.  So he is called person in that sense.This is all vaishnava view not of any one vaishnava sect..

Comment: Alright, there you go. We have the clarification on the meaning of the word "person" at last. If "person" simply means "human", then practically no AchArya worth his salt considers Krishna as mere human.

Comment: @Pratimaputra how about editing as per suggested in moderation room?

Comment: Ambiguous question. You ask whether Krishna can be called as a person and say no translations which use person. If one can be called person, the translator or the commentator will use the word person. Right. It is like asking what is 10+10 and don't use translations which say 20. Do you want to see an answer which do not say that he is not a person?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma thanks so much for your kind advice.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Is it okay now?

Comment: @Pratimaputra let them raise first!!!

Comment: @AkshayS okay.i hv no objection:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how Krishnaprem**, (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna_Prem), **the renowned siddha Gaudiya Vaishnava saint sees the topic**.He clearly answers in the negative and writes

> **Nor Krishna is man at all, but a great Power which, by its presence, though unknown, unseen, lightens the bitter sorrows of the world.**

**The sanskritdictionary.com gives the relevant meanings of 'Purusha' as**

> The soul; द्वाविमौ पुरुषौ लोके क्षरश्चाक्षर एव च Bg.15.16 &c. -7 The Supreme Being, God (soul of the universe); पुरातनं त्वां पुरुषं पुराविदः (विदुः) Śi.1.33; R.13.6.

**It is obvious that here 'Purusha' can NOT mean person ('Vyakti') -- because three types of 'Purusha' are mentioned in the chapter 15 of the Gita: kshara, Akshara and Purusha-Uttama. If all three are translated as persons, that would be the most misleading!**

in His 'The Yoga of the Bhagavad-Gita'. First Sri Krishnaprem clarifies:

> To anyone who has eyes to see, Gita is based on direct knowledge of Reality, and the Path that leads to that Reality..Those eternal realities are the same now as they were thousand of years ago, and the text of Gita should be interpreted in words that refer to these realities here and now.

He explains the verse that contains the word 'Purusha' in chapter 15, sloka 4 of the Gita as

> Detaching himself from  the union with the objects of both outer and inner senses, detaching himself in fact from all from whatsoever, the disciple must soar upon the trackless path of light towards **the Primal Consciousness from which ages past the Cosmic Energied steamed forth. (verse 4)**.That Consciousness however being Absolute, is far beyond all that we know as such.Knower and Known exist in one as it is, in another way, they are not one in absolute matter.It is in fact no consciousness for us, being beyond the Fire of manifested life, the Moon of Mula-prakriti, the Sun of the unmanifested Atman.It is the Void; It is also the Full.Having gone thither, none can return again.That, Krishna says, is His Supreme Abode.That is the Goal; That is final bliss.

Krushnaprem is a foremost intellectual, a greatest Siddha Vaishnava and a top-class writer. So I lay most importance to His translation and interpretation.Those who know a minimum of both Sanskrit and English will understand that the word 'Purusha' can never be satisfactorily translated as 'Person', because The one Who lying in the 'Pura' is 'Purusha'.
 **Sri Krishnprem translates 'Purusha' as 'The Spirit or Consciousness**'.
The entire book is available for download online in pdf format. https://www.auro-ebooks.com/the-yoga-of-the-bhagavat-gita/

**The translations like 'Person' or 'The Supreme Personality of Godhead' are very very close to the Christan Theological meaning and the farthest from what the Gita and the Acharyas try to imply.**

**UPDATE**

There are different meanings of the word 'Purusha' in the dictionary.One crude meaning is a 'Male Person'.But in the Vedanta Literature, that is NOT acceptable. The Upanishad says : 'Purusha' of a size of a thumb always resides in the heart of every human being. The Gita says: There are two types of 'Purusha' --khsara and akshara,metc etc. There is the famous 'Purusha-Sukta' in the Vedas also.So it becomes clear that in the Vedanta Literature that includes the Gita, the translation of 'Purusha' can never be 'Person'.

Also, Srimad-Bhagavatam mentions that Mother Yashoda wrongly took her lad as a person and did bind with rope and Sri Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita quotes this sloka(Madhya, chapter 19):

> tam matvA Atmajam avyaktam martyalingam adokhsajam/gopika udukhale dAmna vavandha prAkritam yathA// (9/12/30)

Comment: Yes Purusha is not a person correct. And knower and known are not different. Yes!!!

Comment: Some Niruktis of Purusha in this answer: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1089/4732

Comment: while it certainly adds value to the site to ask questions only to answer them oneself, it might be misleading to mark one's own answer as the accepted one, even though other answers receive many more upvotes, don't you think?

Comment: @Sahadev if i find the other answers are not correct according to my understanding, I have no way except to choose my answer.Are you new to the site, as so many have been choising their own answers since years?

Comment: @Sahadev and what votes has to do with choosing an answer?

Comment: I‘m indeed new to the site, didn‘t know that it‘s common practice to accept one‘s own answer

Comment: You don't want ISKCON answers but you're okay with Gaudiya Vaishnava answers?

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes. ISKCON is a minor part of Gaudiyas

Comment: @Ikshvaku There has been many realised saints in the Gaudiyas. Like Charan Das Babaji, Ramdas Babaji, Krishnaprem.

Comment: You are unnecessarily emphasising on the word person in the question and the answer both whereas you are trying to prove Krishna is not a Vyakti. You should be writing Sanskrit word rather than English. Because the original word is Sanskrit. Also, "Person" has many meanings in English and there are many dictionaries besides Oxford. The word can also be used to describe some characters. Ramanujacharya and Shankaracharya know more than enough Sanskrit to write bhashyas and they know Krishna is Purusha. They cite a paragraph from Shanti Parva where he incarnated as a human being.

Comment: When you add a shloka which is in non English language, post translation. This is an English language site.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma yes i shall post with some other slokas also.thnx

Answer (score 11):

> Can Sri Krishna be called 'a person'?

**Yes, here is what Ramanujacharya says in the introduction to his Bhagavad Gita Bhashya:**

> Nārāyaṇa is the Consort of Sri, He is absolutely auspicious and is the
>   antithesis of all that is evil. His essential nature consists of Being
>   (sat), Consciousness (cit) and Bliss (ānanda) and these
>   characteristics distinguish Him from all other beings. He is veritably
>   a great ocean of innumerable auspicious attributes which are intrinsic
>   to His nature and cannot be surpassed — some of them being;
>   omniscience, omnipotence, sovereignty, energy, creative potency and
>   glory.
>
> **Nārāyaṇa has a divine form**, which is both pleasing and appropriate.
>   His form is inconceivable, indescribable, divine, eternal and
>   immaculate. He is a repository of limitless perfections such as
>   radiance, beauty, fragrance, tenderness, pervading sweetness and
>   youthfulness. The Lord is adorned with suitable divine ornaments which
>   are diverse, infinite, amazing, eternal, flawless, unlimited and holy.

And here is what Ramanujacharya says about Narayana's incarnation as Krishna:

> Under the pretext of relieving the earth of its burdens, **but really in order to make Himself available
>   for us (frail humans) to take refuge in Him, the Lord incarnated on the earth as Sri Krishna.** He thus
>   manifested Himself to all beings. He engaged in divine pastimes which captivated the minds and
>   hearts of all, high and low. He vanquished demoniac beings such as Pūtana, Śakaṭa, the two Arjuna
>   trees, Ariṣṭa, Prālambha, Dhenuka, Kaliya, Keśin, Kuvalaya-pīḍa, Cānura, Muṣṭika, Tośala and
>   Kaṁsa. He spread joy and beatitude over the entire world with the nectar of His glances and speech,
>   demonstrating His boundless compassion, friendliness and love for all.
>
> When the internecine war between the sons of Pāṇḍu and the descendants of Kuru broke out, Kṛṣṇa,
>   **the Supreme Being**, the God of all gods, overwhelmed by His love for those devotees who had
>   taken refuge in Him, **took upon Himself the humble role of the charioteer of Arjuna, so that He
>   could be seen by all the people**

And also in chapter 15 called "Mystery of the Omnipresent Supreme Being", it is said in verse 4:

> tataḥ padaṃ tat parimārgitavyaṃ yasmin gatā na nivartanti bhūyaḥ |
>   tameva cādyaṃ **puruṣaṃ** prapadye yataḥ pravṛttiḥ prasṛtā purāṇī
>
> One should then seek that goal, attaining which one never returns. **One should take refuge in
>   that Primal Person** from whom this ancient process emanated.

So clearly Krishna can be called a person, and not just by followers of ISKCON.

Comment: purusha does not mean person

Comment: purusha -sukta means about a person?

Comment: Does Purusha necessarily mean a "person" in the sense of a human? I dont think so. Once again, I am asking OP to clarify what he means by the word "person".

Comment: @LazyLubber purusha as opposed to prakriti. Person as opposed to what? Those who are translating Purusha as Person are mistaken

Comment: @Pratimaputra We can avoid extended discussion if you tell exactly what you mean by the word "person", rather than asking to refer to dictionary.

Comment: @Pratimaputra I think you are escaping from giving a direct answer.

Comment: @LazyLubber when person is used.. it is meant to say he is an individual with his own interests,qualities, behavior etc... In English, meanings have to forced a bit...avirbhava and tirobhava, how are you going to translate these at all? Prabhupada uses appearance and disappearance. The meaning becomes clear in purports what exactly is meant. And it is basic Vaishnava philosphy that God is not a body of flesh but suddha sattva

Comment: @LazyLubber Right. If he thinks "person" as in "Jiva" or "ordinary human", then no, Krishna is not an ordinary human trapped in samsara. On the other hand, he is the parama purusha.

Comment: @LazyLubber I hv provided both dictionary meaning and an answer.Hooe I will never hear from you that I am escaping from giving a direct answer. I personally am just no one to give an answer here and I had to search the answer from a Gaudiya Vaishnava which could satisfy me.

Comment: Sri Ramanuja did not write in English. He used the word 'Purusha'. 'Purusha' is a word with a very deep meaning. Person is 'vyakti', NOT 'Purusha'. A crude translation of 'Purusha' is 'Male Person', which if course is not acceptable here. Sari Ramanuja never branded Sri Krishna as a 'Vyakti'. In the sankrit dictionaries, there are several meanings of 'Purusha' by the way. So it seems that you have misrepresented the opinion of your Acharya to prove your point.

Comment: BTW 'Supreme Being' that you have used is a very good translation.

Comment: @Pratimaputra "So it seems that you have misrepresented the opinion of your Acharya to prove your point." | That's why I asked what you mean by "person." Sri Vaishnavas obviously don't believe he's a Jivatma.

Comment: @Ikshvaku i hd provided the dictionary meaning of 'person'. I being in the lineage of Sri Vaishnava myself is a little bit familiar with what Sri Ramanuja could say.Its the translators who very wrongly translate purusha to person.

Comment: @Pratimaputra OK sure.  Thanks for talking to me about this.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan you are welcome

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the word **puruṣa** really means "a person", it's explained like that in the Monier Williams Sanskrit-English Dictionary:

> [L=126439] **a person** , (pumān puruṣaḥ , a male person S3a1n3khGr2. Mn. ; daṇḍaḥp° , punishment personified Mn. ; esp. grammatical pers. ; with prathama , madhyama , uttama = the 3rd , 2nd , 1st pers. Nir. Pa1n2. ), an officer , functionary , attendant , servant Mn. MBh. &c (cf. tat-p°)

And Lord Krishna says in the Bhagavad-gita 15.18 (vedabase translation):

> yasmāt kṣaram atīto ’ham
>   akṣarād api cottamaḥ
>   ato ’smi loke vede ca
>   prathitaḥ **puruṣottamaḥ**
>
> yasmāt — because; kṣaram — to the fallible; atītaḥ — transcendental; aham — I am; akṣarāt — beyond the infallible; api — also; ca — and; uttamaḥ — the best; ataḥ — therefore; asmi — I am; loke — in the world; vede — in the Vedic literature; ca — and; prathitaḥ — celebrated; **puruṣa-uttamaḥ — as the Supreme Personality**.
>
> Because I am transcendental, beyond both the fallible and the infallible, and because I am the greatest, I am celebrated both in the world and in the Vedas as that **Supreme Person**.

And in the following verse 19 that is repeated and there it is said that one who knows Lord Krishna as the Supreme Person without doubting, is the knower of everything, and he therefore engages himself in full devotional service to Lord Krishna.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91901/discussion-on-answer-by-brahma-jijnasa-can-sri-krishna-be-called-a-person).